# WCF and Transport certification

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I have a project that has a requirement whereby we need to expose a simple SOAP 1.1 ack/nack webservice that is secured using TLS and a username/password in the WS-Security header. I have created the following custom binding and behaviour

```
 <binding name="itkService" closeTimeout="00:10:01" openTimeout="00:10:01"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:01" sendTimeout="00:10:00.0000001">
     <sslStreamSecurity requireClientCertificate="true" />
     <security enableUnsecuredResponse="true" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"                            includeTimestamp="true" requireSecurityContextCancellation="true">
         <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="24.20:31:23.6470000" />
         <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="24.20:31:23.6470000" />
         <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" />
     </security>
     <customTextMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" mediaType="text/xml" encoding="utf-8">
           <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="1024" />
     </customTextMessageEncoding>
     <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="10485760" />
</binding>

<behavior name="webHttpEnablingBehaviour">
     <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
     <serviceCredentials>
         <clientCertificate>
              <authentication customCertificateValidatorType="ITKCore.Validation.MyCertificateValidator, ITKCore"
                                certificateValidationMode="Custom" />
         </clientCertificate>
         <serviceCertificate findValue="Sub CA" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindByIssuerName" />
         <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="ITKCore.Validation.UsernameValidator, ITKCore" />

     </serviceCredentials>
 </behavior>
```

However part of the service request validation logic states that we must use the presented TLS certificate and check the subject distinguished name against an access control list. I have had a dig around but cannot see a way to actually retrieve the transport certificate.

Does anyone have any advice on how I would go about this in WCF?